# why the Elm Architecture is called TEA?

Tags: elm, elm-architecture

I've seen this `TEA` acronym (?!) in many places all over the web - means elm architecture - but i don't understand **what each initial stands for.** Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TEA is an acronym of the name  ***T**he **E**lm **A**rchitecture*

Answer (score 4):

A little resume, of course the answer short, correct and sweet was provided by @bdukes:

> The Elm Architecture is a simple pattern for architecting webapps. It
>   is great for modularity, code reuse, and testing. Ultimately, it makes
>   it easy to create complex web apps that stay healthy as you refactor
>   and add features.

More info [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/)